# Paging and results count on new global search are off

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, global-search

The paging on the new global search is ... off ...

When I [search for `test`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=test), it promises me 3,332,097 results, which would lead to 111069 pages:

[image]

However, when I click on the [last page button <kbd>111069</kbd>](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=test&page=111069), the number of search results is reduced to 2,698,280 (89942 pages):

[image]

As @Catija mentions, it looks like the default is 15 results per page, and not 30 as indicated by the highlight.

Comment: There's also not 30 results per page... :/

Comment: 30 is the new 15, it seems ...